# Running an infinite loop in cron job

Tags: php, cron, webserver

Running an infinite loop in cron job.
Suppose, i have written a php based script to run on my server computer using cron job, and i want to use infinite loop in that php script.
Any ideas for running an infinite loop in cron job.

Comment: Hmmm, I really have to ask why it has to be an implicit infinite loop, before I'll throw 100 arguments at you why you should avoid that approach ;)

Answer (score 3):

Infinite looping applications are usually called daemons. They are system services that offer some kind of constant processing and/or the readiness to accept some potential incoming processing activities.

[Gearman](http://gearman.org/) is a system daemon you can install than can handle various tasks you give it. It's a complex tools that allows many things but it could be used to implement your necessities.

[PHP::Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) is a Gearman client that talks to the Gearman daemon and sends tasks to the daemon specifying the conditions under which the task must be executed.

The limitations that @Jeffrey emphasized about PHP are true because PHP was designed as a share nothing architecture (one page load equals one script execution - each page load works under its own data context).

Perhaps [System Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) (a pear package) may assist in overcoming some or all of the limitations mentioned above. I haven't used it so I can't tell you much more about it but it's as good a place to start as any.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation ... actually i am new to coding n having lot'ss troubles... buy the way, can we run a script for 1 hour by using `sleep();` in my server computer?

Comment: You have to [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) because the default value is `30s`. During the time that `sleep()` is running you can't do anything else so there is little point in using `sleep()` unless you want the application to actually "wait" for something else.